# How to open sub window and draw/paint the shapes in c# using abstract factory design pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am working on a simple command-line graphical application in c#. [image]
Just like above, after clicking debug/run or typing run in below window, Program checks predefined syntax line by line.

```
        private void execute()
            {
                Output outputWindow = new Output(); //object of output window 
                compiler = new Compiler(outputWindow); //sending object of output window to compiler
                //get all text and save in lines string array
                string output = "";
                string[] lines = GetActiveEditor().Lines;
                lines = lines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
                if (lines == null || lines.Length == 0)
                {
                    consoleBox.Text += "\n Error: Compiling Failed. Empty File.";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        output = compiler.Compile(line);
                        consoleBox.Text += "\n" + output;
                        if (output.Contains("Error"))
                        {
                        break;
                        }
                    }

                }


            }

            private void ToolBtnDebug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                consoleBox.Clear();
                consoleBox.Text = " \n CPaint Compiler:- Compiling Started... \n";
                execute();
            }

    // In Compiler 

        string[] commands = { "clear", "reset", "rectangle", "circle", "triangle", "position pen", "pen draw" };
        Public string Line { get; set; }
        Public Output outputWindow;

        public Compiler(Output form)
            {
                outputWindow = form;
            }

        //checks syntax
        public bool IsSyntax(string syntax)
            {
                bool result = false;
                if (Array.Exists(commands, element => element == syntax.ToLower().Trim()))
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                return result;
            }

    //Compile class 
    public string Compile(string line)
            {
                string output = "";
                //splitting the line by comma"," and small brackets "()" and assigning into an string a`enter code here`rray
                string[] code = line.Split(',', '(', ')');
                //removing extra spaces 
                code = code.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
    bool checkSyntax = IsSyntax(code[0]);
                if (checkSyntax == true)
                {
                  if (code[0].Trim().ToLower().Equals("circle"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                                int parameter1 = Int32.Parse(code[1]);
                                int parameter2 = Int32.Parse(code[2]);
                                //string shapeType = "circle";

                                ShapeFactory shapeFactory = new ShapeFactory();
                                Circle circle = shapeFactory.GetShape("circle").Shape as Circle;
                                circle.Draw(12, 12);
                                output = "command executed successfully: parameter is" + parameter1;
                                //      output = "is numeric ";
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
                            output = "\n Parameter Error : Invalid/Insufficient Parameter. \n";
                        }

                    }
```

In Shape Factory Method:

```
class ShapeFactory:AbstractFactory
{
    public override FactoryShape GetShape(string shapeType)
    {
        FactoryShape factoryShape = null;
        if (shapeType.Equals("circle"))
        {
            factoryShape = new FactoryShape(new Circle());
        }

        return factoryShape;
    }
}
        //Circle Method Code: 
            namespace CPaint.Class
            {
            class Circle
            {
                Graphics graphics;
                public void Draw(float initX, float initY)
                {
                    Output outputWindow=new Output();
                    Graphics graphics=outputWindow.outputArea.CreateGraphics();
                    outputWindow.outputArea.Image=Color.Red;
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
                    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 12, 12, 12, 12);
                    graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 12, 12, 12, 12);
                    Console.WriteLine("ok drawing circle for you" + initX + "   " + initY);
output.show();
                }
            }
            }
```

This code opens two read empty output window, instead it should draw two circles in same output window.
Please help, I got stuck here since three days. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The usual way to draw on a control's surface is to get its `Graphics` object and draw into it. `output.outputArea.CreateGraphics().DrawEllipse(pen, 12, 12, 12, 12);` Please don't forget to dispose the object. Please use it in a using() block..

Comment: I did the Same, but also I it also cant draw.
`output.outputArea.BackColor = Color.Red;` This Works but `output.outputArea.CreateGraphics().DrawEllipse(pen, 12, 12, 12, 12);` this dont.

Comment: What is output? What type is it? Where is it declared?

Comment: color is changed but `output.outputArea.CreateGraphics().DrawEllipse(pen, 12, 12, 12, 12);` doesnot show any changes.

Comment: What is output? What type is it? Where is it declared?

Comment: like said earlier, I have Mainform calls Compiler class and compiler class calls Draw Method. this code is written in Draw Method. Draw Method should open Output window change the background color to red and draw circle. but it only changes background color.

Comment: What is " New Separate Output Window "? Is it an empty form? Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise, you can get no help.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I made two forms, one for showing output and one for writing code which is main form. For example: user writes `circle (20)` and press run, then program should open new window i.e Output Form/Window and draw the circle. I hope you get it.

Comment: Ok. So you just open an empty form and draw on the surface of it. Let's see what I can do.

Comment: I did a very small application with two forms. I showed the Output form and draw on it using output.CreateGraphics().DrawEllipse() and it worked. I think what you need is something else. Can you please share the code where you create the output form? If you need to pass the Graphics object of the new output form, just get it with output.CreateGraphics() and pass this to the shape so it can use this graphics object to draw on.

Comment: Add a `Graphics graphics` parameter to your `Draw` method and pass the return value of `output.CreateGraphcis()`

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul : _The usual way to draw on a control's surface is to get its Graphics object and draw into it._ Um, __not if you want your output to persist!__ - You need to use a Paint event and its e.Graphics parameter..

Comment: _can't initialize PaintEventArgs_ Indeed! - You need to code the Paint event of the target cotrol..and unse Invaldate to trigger it.

Comment: @TaW That is correct. It won't persist my way. But since he did not share the code, we don't know what he is trying to do and where. Dear Dinesh. You should not call the Paint method yourself. The run-time should call it. While creating the output form, pass your shape object into it and keep it in a field. Then in the paint method, when it is invoked (by the run-time) just call `circle.Draw(e.Graphics, 12, 12)`. You still need to add Graphics parameter yo your Draw methods.

Comment: _You should not call the Paint method yourself. The run-time should call it._ To make it do so call yourControl.Invalöidate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need to improve your design.

1. The factory pattern makes sense only if you are coding to abstraction, which means, the factory should create the concrete type, but you should not know the concrete type but only the abstract type. This is not the case in your design. You say that you are using abstract factory pattern, but you cast the created object to Circle, which is "coding to implementation".
2. The Compiler both compiles the lines to Shapes, and executes them. A compiler should only transform text (code) into an executable object, and should not execute them. Unfortunately, with your current design, it is not possible to pass the created shapes into the output form and have them drawn.
3. You need to pass all the compiled Shapes into your output form, and should draw in OnPaint override where the run-time is re-drawing the surface of the Control (form)

The abstraction (Shape):

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract void Draw(Graphics surface);
}
```

And the concrete types:

```
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics surface)
    {
        surface.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Radius, Radius);
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics surface)
    {
        surface.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);
    }
}
```

Here is the ShapeFactory in my implementation

```
public class ShapeFactory
{
    public static Shape CreateShape(string shapeName, params string[] parameters)
    {
        switch (shapeName)
        {
            case "circle":
                return new Circle() { Radius = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[0]) };
            case "rectangle":
                return new Rectangle { Width = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[0]), Height = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[1]) };
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("shapeName");
        }
    }
}
```

The Compiler:

```
public Shape Compile(string line)
{
    string[] code = line.Split(new char[] { ',', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (IsSyntax(code[0]))
    {
        try
        {
            return ShapeFactory.CreateShape(code[0], code.Skip(1).ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception shapeCreationException)
        {
            // Exception handling here.
            // . . .
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Syntax Error handling here
        // . . .
    }
    return null;
}
```

And finally the output form:

```
public partial class Output : Form
{
    public List<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }

    public Output()
    {
        Shapes = new List<Shape>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Shape shapeToDraw in Shapes)
        {
            shapeToDraw.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

and the execute() method:

```
private void execute()
{
    Output outputWindow = new Output();
    Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

    string[] lines = { "circle(24)", "rectangle(80,56)" };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        try
        {
            Shape compiledShape = compiler.Compile(line);
            outputWindow.Shapes.Add(compiledShape);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Exception handling here
            // . . .
        }
    }

    outputWindow.Show();
    outputWindow.Invalidate();
}
```

This is tested and works.

Please comment if you don't understand something or can't get this work, but unfortunately, your case don't have a simple fix because of its design flaws.

Comment: I tried the same code, but also it does not draw circle and rectangle.

Comment: On my system it does, and on yours, if you implemented it correctly, it should. Can you upload your full source code somewhere so I can fix it?

Comment: I have uploaded in google drive. here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YHmA-vKEqtD3udfP3XI3BHfKuZSxidJW?usp=sharing

Comment: The Image outputArea is completely covering the form surface (Dock = Fill). The code is currently painting on the form directly. Do you have to draw into this Image control? If No, just remove the outputArea control. If yes, I will update my answer, it is also achievable.

Comment: no, that is not required. I removed that picture box. Its working. Thank you soo much.

Comment: You are welcome. The appropriate usage of the factory pattern can open new doors for you, you know. Be safe, and good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211231/discussion-between-dinesh-k-shrestha-and-oguz-ozgul).

Comment: Hello again, How can I display error messages like, invalid syntax, invalid parameters and failed to draw to user? since I cant return any message..